# NetworkBoundResource make consecutive calls

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines

I have a project based on the Android Architecture Component in kotlin.
I have a classic abstract NetworkBoundResource used in the Repository that return a LiveData to the ViewModel.

In the viewModel I call the repository method like this and bind the livedata to a MediatorLiveData

```
repository.login(LoginInput(username, password)).apply {
    bindObserver(_loginToken, this)
}

protected fun <R> bindObserver(observer: MediatorLiveData<R>?, source: LiveData<R>) {
    observer?.apply {
        addSource(source) {
            postValue(it)
        }
    }
}
```

I have to call 3 WebService after login is completed (so 3 methods in the Repository that return LiveData variable) in a sequential way. It's possible to do this in one coroutine waiting for the response of the live data?

This is what I want to do (all in viewmodel if it's possible):

```
login
wait for data
get a parameter for the response    
call another ws
wait for response
call another ws
wait for response
call another ws    
wait for response
update LiveData in ViewModel (observed in Fragment)
```